# Sample integral points in m-Ball

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

The problem I have is pretty simple, however I cannot find an answer.
I need an *efficient* algorithm to sample integral points within an m-dimensional ball of radius r around the origin (Euclidean norm) uniformly. I want to sample uniformly from the set
$$
S = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}^m | x \in \mathcal{B}^m(r)\}.
$$
The obvious approach is rejection sampling, i.e. uniformly sample integral points within the m-dimensional box with coordinates between $-r$ and $r$ and reject those samples with norm $\geq r$.
However this approach is not efficient, as for $m=40$ this already takes several minutes ($r=40$).
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is large compared to $\sqrt{m}$ you may proceed as follows.

You may sample a vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ of $m$ independent normal-distributed variables, and divide each coordinate $x_i$ of that vector by the length $\sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_m^2}$ of the vector. This gives you a uniform-distributed vector on the surface of the unit ball. Then you sample a variable $0 \leq z \leq r+s$  with distribution function proportional to $z^m$ for $0 \leq z \leq r+s$,
for a constant $s$ to be discussed later.

Then you multiply the vector with $z$ and round the coordinates
of the result vector to the nearest integer. You accept the vector if it has length $\leq r$ and reject is otherwise.

In case $s =\sqrt{m}/2$ you get a uniform distribution of the integer points in the ball $\mathcal{B}^m(r)$. But then the rejection rate is high if  $r$ is not much larger than $\sqrt{m}$. If you can live with a smaller probability for choosing a point close to the boundary you may also use a smaller value for $s$.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean exactly with "sample z proportional to z^m"? You mean uniformly in the interval between 0 and r+s?

Comment: that can be done with an inverse cumulant transform, an in this case it is quite simple, you want $X^{\frac 1 m}$ where X is uniform

Comment: Operationally, this means we need to sample a $u$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ and then compute $z=(r+s)\cdot u^{1/m}$, correct?

Comment: @N.P. Yes, that is correct.